# JavaScript in Grails's GSP page

Tags: javascript, grails

how I can run impromtu js code inside the grails g:if statement? I want to run Error alert windows or success alert window. my code is

```
<g:if test="${flash.error}">
    <g:javascript>invokePopup(${flash.error})</g:javascript>
</g:if>
```

and in my main.js

```
function invokePopup(message) {
   $.prompt(message);
}
```

nothing happened in this case and YES, a added main.js to ApplicationResources.groovy

Comment: Have you verified the source of the page in the browser as including main.js? What errors if any are you getting? I suspect you need to wrap ${flash.error} in quotes of some sort or it will likely not be a valid javascript string too.

Comment: there is no any error in browser console.

Comment: Okay, but in the source for the page in your browser do you see it including your main.js file? Post the source for the page as your browser renders it.

Comment: I got this error now: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `flash.error` contains a `String` value the following line needs to change to avoid unexpected identifier errors.

```
<g:if test="${flash.error}">
    <g:javascript>invokePopup("${flash.error}")</g:javascript>
</g:if>
```

Notice that `flash.error` is now outputted inside quotes.